# Can't call class of reference

Tags: c#, class, reference

I added a reference to my project called core_language.
but when i try to call a class of the reference it is not working correctly

when i call the class like this it is working fine.

```
_resourceManager = core_language.Resources.ResourceManager;
```

But this way is not working and i dont know why, i already put the
 `using core_langugage;` on the top of the page

```
   _resourceManager = Resources.ResourceManager;
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why did you assign two times the same _resourceManager variable?

Comment: the "Resources" in your code refers to System.Resources...remove System.Resources.... it will work

Comment: Don´t post screenshots of your code, copy the code into the question instead. This makes it easier for future readers to find your question via search-engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem probably occurs because `Ressources` is an ambigioues name. The compiler can´t determine if by writing `Ressources.RessourceManager` you refer to the ressources found within your referenced project (`core_language`) or those within the project this code is defined in (`mijn_energiefactuur`) .

To avoid this you should use a qualified name of the type you want to access:

```
var manager1 = core_language.Ressources.RessourceManager;
var manager2 = System.Ressources.RessourceManager;
```

Alternativly simply remove the `using`-statement for `System.Ressources`. Then calls to `Ressources` will reflect `core_language.Ressource`.